# How to convert list of lists to bytes?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I have list of list float and I want to convert it into bytes. Can please some help me to do this.
for example

```
l = [[0.1, 1.0, 2.0], [2.0, 3.1, 4.1]]
```

and I want something like

```
bytes(l) -> b'\x01\x02\x03.......'
```

Comment: You need to be more clear, you want to convert a list of list to a byte string? But which elements of the list, and how will they be placed in the string?

Comment: How do this values map to the result?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you've tagged this `numpy`, this is simply [`tobytes`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.tobytes.html)

```
a = np.array(l)
a.tobytes()
```

```
b'\x9a\x99\x99\x99\x99\x99\xb9?\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xf0?\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00@\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00@\xcd\xcc\xcc\xcc\xcc\xcc\x08@ffffff\x10@'
```

---

This result can be re-processed as an `ndarray` using [`frombuffer`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.frombuffer.html), but the original shape will not be maintained.

Answer (score -1):

Hopefully this is what you wanted:

```
import struct

input = [[0.1, 1.0, 2.0], [2.0, 3.1, 4.1]]
outs = list()
string = ""

for i in input:
    for j in i:
        outs.append(bytes(struct.pack("f", j)))

for i in outs:
    string += str(i)
    print(i)

print('Bytes:', string)
```

Answer (score -1):

This is the correct question to the question. There are built-in Python solutions that do not require dependencies on numpy, which is what the original question is asking. Here is the proper solution:

First: convert the list of lists to a single list using

```
from itertools import chain
matrix = [[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8]]
array_1d = list(chain.from_iterable(matrix))
assert array_1d == [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

Next: convert a list of Python native types (ints in this case) to bytes:

```
b = bytes(array_1d)
assert b == b'\x01\x02\x03\x04\x05\x06\x07\x08'
```